# Cannot find module 'parseuri'

Tags: javascript, socket.io

When I create the `app.js` with content:

```
    var app = require('express')();

    var http = require('http').Server(app);

    var io = require('socket.io')(http);

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

    http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I got the error :

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'parseuri'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspace\Node\node_modules\socket.io\lib\url.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Thanks for supporting !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... you should read the error first, if it says you don't have the module "parseuri", install it then.

Make a folder named "node_modules" on the root dir of your project, then go to the console and type `npm install parseuri` or `npm install -g parseuri` to make it global.

That's all i can help with the info you gave.

You can also look search for modules info in [the official npm page](https://www.npmjs.org/), here's for [parseuri](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parseuri)

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to you having `parseuri` and `parseUri` in your project. That was the problem I had in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7933

You can fix it with `npm-shrinkwrap` or manually installing the `socket.io` package that relies on it.