# why does npm start fail?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to run some React code but receiving this error on vs code. I am not sure what the issue is.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'parseurl'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js
- C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\express\index.js
- C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js
- C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Programming\Projects\apexgrade\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:18:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Programming\\Projects\\apexgrade\\node_modules\\finalhandler\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Programming\\Projects\\apexgrade\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\application.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Programming\\Projects\\apexgrade\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\express.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Programming\\Projects\\apexgrade\\node_modules\\express\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Programming\\Projects\\apexgrade\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\lib\\Server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Programming\\Projects\\apexgrade\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```

i have tried using npm install, but that doesnt seem to solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module 'parseuri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360313/cannot-find-module-parseuri)

Comment: it didn't work, it is still giving me the same errors

Answer (score 0):

I think your package-lock.json don't have `parseurl` package. Since `parseurl` is dependency of `express`. Try to install parseurl with command.
run step by step follow bellow command.

1. `npm uninstall express`
2. `npm install express`

or `npm install parseurl`